# How to move/copy first element of an array (which is object) to another array without getting [object Object]?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I've got a card deck written as an array of objects, and wanted to take the first element of that array, and move it to another array. I thought it will be super easy, that it will only need to use `shift()` on the cardDeck array, save it in one variable and then pass it with `push()` to the player1 array. But no matter which method I will use, I always and with [object Object], so I think it get's passed but maybe one level "deeper" than I would like.

I tried using `push()`, `shift()`, even `push.apply()` and `player1.concat(drawnedCard)`.

The array of cards:

```
let cardDeck;

cardDeck = [
    {"cardName": "Ace",
    "cardColor": "Clubs",
    "strength": 1
    },
    {"cardName": "2",
        "cardColor": "Clubs",
        "strength": 2
    },
    {"cardName": "3",
    "cardColor": "Clubs",
    "strength": 3
    },
    {"cardName": "4",
    "cardColor": "Clubs",
    "strength": 4
    },
    {"cardName": "5",
        "cardColor": "Clubs",
        "strength": 5
    },
    {"cardName": "6",
    "cardColor": "Clubs",
    "strength": 6
    },
    {"cardName": "7",
    "cardColor": "Clubs",
    "strength": 7
    },
    {"cardName": "8",
        "cardColor": "Clubs",
        "strength": 8
    },
    {"cardName": "9",
    "cardColor": "Clubs",
    "strength": 9
    },
    {"cardName": "10",
    "cardColor": "Clubs",
    "strength": 10
    },
    {"cardName": "Jack",
        "cardColor": "Clubs",
        "strength": 11
    },
    {"cardName": "Queen",
    "cardColor": "Clubs",
    "strength": 12
    },
    {"cardName": "King",
    "cardColor": "Clubs",
    "strength": 13
    },
    {"cardName": "Ace",
    "cardColor": "Diamonds",
    "strength": 1
    },
    {"cardName": "2",
        "cardColor": "Diamonds",
        "strength": 2
    },
    {"cardName": "3",
    "cardColor": "Diamonds",
    "strength": 3
    },
    {"cardName": "4",
    "cardColor": "Diamonds",
    "strength": 4
    },
    {"cardName": "5",
        "cardColor": "Diamonds",
        "strength": 5
    },
    {"cardName": "6",
    "cardColor": "Diamonds",
    "strength": 6
    },
    {"cardName": "7",
    "cardColor": "Diamonds",
    "strength": 7
    },
    {"cardName": "8",
        "cardColor": "Diamonds",
        "strength": 8
    },
    {"cardName": "9",
    "cardColor": "Diamonds",
    "strength": 9
    },
    {"cardName": "10",
    "cardColor": "Diamonds",
    "strength": 10
    },
    {"cardName": "Jack",
        "cardColor": "Diamonds",
        "strength": 11
    },
    {"cardName": "Queen",
    "cardColor": "Diamonds",
    "strength": 12
    },
    {"cardName": "King",
    "cardColor": "Diamonds",
    "strength": 13
    },
    {"cardName": "Ace",
    "cardColor": "Hearts",
    "strength": 1
    },
    {"cardName": "2",
        "cardColor": "Hearts",
        "strength": 2
    },
    {"cardName": "3",
    "cardColor": "Hearts",
    "strength": 3
    },
    {"cardName": "4",
    "cardColor": "Hearts",
    "strength": 4
    },
    {"cardName": "5",
        "cardColor": "Hearts",
        "strength": 5
    },
    {"cardName": "6",
    "cardColor": "Hearts",
    "strength": 6
    },
    {"cardName": "7",
    "cardColor": "Hearts",
    "strength": 7
    },
    {"cardName": "8",
        "cardColor": "Hearts",
        "strength": 8
    },
    {"cardName": "9",
    "cardColor": "Hearts",
    "strength": 9
    },
    {"cardName": "10",
    "cardColor": "Hearts",
    "strength": 10
    },
    {"cardName": "Jack",
        "cardColor": "Hearts",
        "strength": 11
    },
    {"cardName": "Queen",
    "cardColor": "Hearts",
    "strength": 12
    },
    {"cardName": "King",
    "cardColor": "Hearts",
    "strength": 13
    },
    {"cardName": "Ace",
    "cardColor": "Spades",
    "strength": 1
    },
    {"cardName": "2",
        "cardColor": "Spades",
        "strength": 2
    },
    {"cardName": "3",
    "cardColor": "Spades",
    "strength": 3
    },
    {"cardName": "4",
    "cardColor": "Spades",
    "strength": 4
    },
    {"cardName": "5",
        "cardColor": "Spades",
        "strength": 5
    },
    {"cardName": "6",
    "cardColor": "Spades",
    "strength": 6
    },
    {"cardName": "7",
    "cardColor": "Spades",
    "strength": 7
    },
    {"cardName": "8",
        "cardColor": "Spades",
        "strength": 8
    },
    {"cardName": "9",
    "cardColor": "Spades",
    "strength": 9
    },
    {"cardName": "10",
    "cardColor": "Spades",
    "strength": 10
    },
    {"cardName": "Jack",
        "cardColor": "Spades",
        "strength": 11
    },
    {"cardName": "Queen",
    "cardColor": "Spades",
    "strength": 12
    },
    {"cardName": "King",
    "cardColor": "Spades",
    "strength": 13
    }
]
```

```
player1 = [];
 player2 = [];
 drawnedCard = [];

 drawnedCard = cardDeck.shift();
 player1.push(drawnedCard);
// player1 = player1.concat(drawnedCard);
```

I would expect to end with:

`player1 = [{"cardName": "Ace", "cardColor": "Clubs", "strength": 1}]` to be able to push another elements from cardDeck array to the player.

But I end up with `player1 = [object Object]`

Comment: Where are you seeing `[object Object]`? That means that it isn't being parsed into a string correctly, not necessarily that there's anything wrong with the structure.

Comment: You end up with? I'm assuming you mean that you're printing the result. If you print the card as a string, you'll get ```[object Object]```.

Comment: Can you supply the full declaration of cardDeck.
Your code here seems fine so far.

Comment: I see [object Object] when I do console.log(player1) or console.log(player1[0]) and I thought i will see this first object from cardDeck array being pushed to the player1 at the last element (which actually at the beginning is index 0, hence it's an empty array)

Comment: What about console.log(JSON.stringify(player1)) ? If you print JSON object or use toString() method, you will not get content, but such a short type description which looks like object containing object in mentioned case.

Comment: The code seem to work https://jsfiddle.net/sh12r9tn/ could you edit your post and show us how you print the result.

Comment: @koziol_matol Can you add the part of the code that includes the `console.log`?

Comment: I switched from Firefox to Chrome, and now it shows everything like it should be, and it seems that really everything worked just fine, but simply in Chrome it shown in better way. But also @Tom 's comment with json.stringify worked as well. Thank you Guys!